# Trigger an Event when a Variable Value Changes

Tags: c#, event-handling

Maybe my question will confuse you.

I want to trigger an event based on my string value changed.

I know that it is possible to trigger an event when the string value changed.

But the problem is: I don't know when the string value will change.

To solve this, continuously monitor the the string value change with timer.

But I need a better solution for this.

Got confused, huh?

---

> For Example,
>
> > I have one DLL, say, MyDll.dll.
> >
> > MyDll has one variable named STATUS
> >
> > This variable has two values, either "Success" or "InProgress".
> >
> > "Success" - if a method, say, LongProcess, completed. "InProgress" - if LongProcess is still processing.
>
> In my program, I need to trigger an event if the MyDll.STATUS has a "Success" value.

To achieve this, I can use a timer control to continuously monitor when the value changed to "Success".

But I want some better way to achieve this. Any suggestion?

Comment: If you can make the string into a string property, you can use its setter do trigger whatever else you want to happen..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than using a field, or an auto property, you can specifically define the get/set behaviour of a property (with a backing field).
In this way you can then trigger actions/events whenever the value of that property changes. For example ...

```
private Status _myStatus;
public Status MyStatus
{
    get { return _myStatus; }
    set 
      {
        if (value == _myStatus) return;
        _myStatus = value;
       // RAISE YOUR EVENT HERE
      }
}
```

This example will allow an event to be raised whenever the value of `MyStatus` changes. Obviously I've made an assumption that the `Type` of `MyStatus` is `Status` so just change that to `string` or whatever the type is.

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.

Answer (score 0):

In that case create a property instead of variable. On its set part raise an event on which you can attach a handler and listen to.

Like this

```
private string _status;
Public Event OnStatusChanged;

public string Status
{
    get
    {
        return _status;
    }
    set
    {
        _status = value;
        RaiseEvent OnStatusChanged;
    }
}
```

Comment: i agree with your point. but its a DLL given by Some one. I can use it Only.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with NO CODING.

For a boolean: 1) Create a checkbox on a form. 2) Double-click on the checkbox. Done.

VS created, linked, and navigated you to edit a new function that gets called whenever the checkbox changes, whether the user clicked on the control or the program code *actually changed* the value. Assigning it the same value has no effect. (tested)

```
...
// Demonstrate behavior:
checkBox1.Checked = false;  // does not trigger checkBox1_CheckedChanged (the first time) because the form defaulted it to false)
checkBox1.Checked = false;  // does not trigger checkBox1_CheckedChanged
checkBox1.Checked = true;   // triggers checkBox1_CheckedChanged
checkBox1.Checked = true;   // does not trigger checkBox1_CheckedChanged
checkBox1.Checked = false;  // triggers checkBox1_CheckedChanged
checkBox1.Checked = false;  // does not trigger checkBox1_CheckedChanged
...

private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Modal pop-up to display checkBox1.Checked (it converts to "False" or "True"):
  MessageBox.Show(new Form() {TopMost=true,TopLevel=true}, "Checked =" + checkBox1.Checked, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

Drawback: Not the best design pattern. You now have a spurious field on your form (unless you wanted it there). You can disable it to prevent user from toggling it, and it will still work. (tested) You can make it invisible, but it is still "there". To take it off the form, you have to replace the GUI code that you borrowed.

Horror: The value or property checkBox1.Checked gets updated before checkBox1_CheckedChanged is called, but the checkbox on the form *does not update until **after*** checkBox1_CheckedChanged returns. Even if you call `this.Update()`. (tested) (Tested on VS2010 targeting .NET 3.0.)

Comment: And to do it for a property that isn't a boolean? Or one that doesn't involve a UI?